# Xcode 6.1.1 LLVM/Yosemite breakpoints not working in Mac OS project

Tags: debugging, xcode6, breakpoints

I have several projects recently moved up to Xcode 6.1.1 from Xcode 4.6.

The iOS projects debug as expected, but the Mac OS projects do not. Breakpoints have no effect. Code execution continues without stopping.

Is this a known issue? Is there a suggested solution?